# Azure Monitor - Pass variable in Log Analytics query using PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I am trying create Log Analytics query based Alert Rule using PowerShell script and command: `New-AzScheduledQueryRule`.

Here I am trying to declare a variable called $ResourceGroup and `$SubscriptionID` in PowerShell script and want to use this in Log analytics query, so I can call script and pass arguments of Resource Group and subscription and Log Alert Query Rule will be created for scope of ResourceGroup. But when I try to deploy the Log query Alert Rule, the variables are not recognized inside query.

```
`$query='AzureMetrics
| where ResourceId has "Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls" 
| where MetricName=="FirewallHealth"
| where Maximum <100
| project FirewallHealth=toint(Maximum),Resource, ResourceGroup'
$source = New-AzScheduledQueryRuleSource -Query $query -DataSourceId "/subscriptions/$SubscriptionIDWS/resourcegroups/$ResourceGroupWS/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/$LogAnalyticsWSName" -QueryType ResultCount

New-AzScheduledQueryRule -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupLAWorkspace -Location "eastus" -Action $alertingAction -Enabled $true -Description $($AlertDescription) -Schedule $schedule -Source $source -Name $($AlertName)
```

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried to fix it and what were the results?
Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: I have updated the question,, hope it should be clear now.